# HTTP Post File From Android App To ASP.NET page, Request.files always empty

Tags: android, asp.net, http, android-async-http

I am fairly new to android coming from and iOS background. I am trying to do a simple task of sending a file (a profile image that the user selects) to my asp.net page to store on my server.

I am 99% certain that I am getting the correct file and sending it off with the current code I am running. The problem is in my ASP.NET file the request of the file object never gets any data.

Here is the ASP.NET Page

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script runat="server"> 

    Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim MyFilecollection As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
        Response.Write("The count is " & MyFilecollection.Count)

        'End If

    End Sub
</script>
```

Where the response I get back to the app is always "0"

I have tried so many different ways of sending the file that I don't know if its prudent to list them here but I've mainly been trying with the AsyncHttpClient library like so:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mygreatapp/userPhoto.jpg");
String connString = "myserverpag.aspx";
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("picture", file,"image/jpeg");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
System.out.println(params);
client.post(connString, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        System.out.println(response);
        Log.w("async", "success!!!!");
    }      

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
    System.out.println(response);
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

And finally if I do my post to http://httpbin.org/post I can see that in fact my post contains data in the "files" object

```
{
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post",
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "origin": "76.101.127.54",
  "files": {
    "picture": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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  },
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "4114",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=_PbbbesptaYhtEYTBDGjHF4U6F_T1n",
    "Connection": "close",
    "User-Agent": "android-async-http/1.4.4 (http://loopj.com/android-async-http)",
    "X-Request-Id": "b54d172b-940c-4281-9e71-e87829e888e1",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Heroku-Request-Id": "b54d172b-940c-4281-9e71-e87829e888e1"
  },
  "form": {},
  "json": null
}
```

Comment: make sure your http headers of post request contains 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'